# How can I resolve Circular import?

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name ='store'
urlpattherns =[
path('', views.all_products,name ='all_products')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please some should help me resolve this error.I keep getting 'The included URLconf '<module 'store.urls' from 'C:\\Use.XX\\XXX\\Desktop\\Ecommerce\\store\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import'

Comment: Try suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648512/cant-fix-does-not-appear-to-have-any-patterns-in-it-if-you-see-valid-patterns and please fix the formatting of your question, and add your actual question.

Comment: a true circular import can be resolved via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python and might also be via try except.  your case is more likely as above.

Comment: @CHNguyen and Abel .Thanks for your suggestions but am yet to resolve the problem